# How to use table name with spaces in Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2

I'm writing an `ActiveRecord` class that uses a MS-SQL server with a schema that has spaces in table and column names. I have no control over the schema. If I use "Job Queue Entry" as the `tableName()` Yii parses that as the table "Job Queue" with alias "Entry" (Yes, there's also a "Job Queue" table...). I've tried everything I could think of to escape the table name with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may quote table name yourself, Yii should not touch quoted names:

```
public static function tableName() {
    return '[Job Queue Entry]';
}
```

Or quote it dynamically based on current DB settings:

```
public static function tableName() {
    $db = static::getDb();
    return $db->quoteTableName($db->tablePrefix . 'Job Queue Entry');
}
```

Comment: I tried quoting the table myself, with ` and with [ ] and with {{ }}. Nothing works. With ` I get: The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM [\`INTIS$Job Queue] [Entry\`]'

Comment: That's the real world name of the table btw, it's used by Microsoft Dynamics NAV

Comment: I don't have access to MSSQL, but I tested it with MySQL and ``return '`Job Queue Entry`';`` works fine. Did you tried second example?

Comment: Seems to be QueryBuilder::quoteTableNames() that is the culprit, and I can't find a way to keep it from treating my table names as tablename + alias